# Проблемка с модальным окном

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот есть такое модальное окно:

```js
var num = 15;

var modalBtn = document.querySelector('.open');
var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');

var modalContainer = document.querySelector('.modals');
var holdModals = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('modal-drop');
  div.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vh';
  div.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 'vw';
  div.style.transitionDelay = Math.random() + 's';
  holdModals.appendChild(div);
}
console.log();
modalContainer.appendChild(holdModals);

modalBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  modalContainer.style.display = 'block';  
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    modalContainer.classList.add('active');
  },0.1);
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
   modalContainer.classList.remove('active');
  
   window.setTimeout(function(){
    modalContainer.style.display = 'none';
  },3000);
});
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.modals {
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  
  &.active {    
    .modal-drop {
      transform-origin: 50%;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    
    .modal-content {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: 0.5s ease-in 1.5s;
    }
  }
}

.modal-drop {
  background: hsl(250,30%,10%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150vh;
  height: 150vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -75vh;
  margin-top: -75vh;
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(.25,1,.60,1), transform-origin 0s;
  transform: scale(0.001);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.modal-content {
  background: hsl(250,30%,10%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s 0s;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50em;  
}

/* Page Styling */

$font-size: 18/16*1em;

::selection {
  background: hsl(40,100%,65%);
  color: #fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: hsl(40,100%,65%);
  color: #fff;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: hsl(30,10%,90%);
  color: hsl(200,50%,20%);
  font: #{$font-size}/1.65 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20em;
  padding: 3em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  
  &::before {
    content: '';
    border: 1px dotted hsl(165,80%,70%);
    position: absolute;
      top: 1.25em;
      right: 1.25em;
      bottom: 1.25em;
      left: 1.25em;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  p {
    margin: 0.5em 0 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(149,70%,90%);
    //text-align: center;
    //font-style: italic;
    //font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  }
}

.open,
.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(149,65%,74%),hsl(155,67%,68%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(155,67%,68%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(165,70%,55%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(165,70%,55%);
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%) contrast(120%);
  }
  
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(149,65%,74%);
    outline: none;
  }
  
  float: right;
}

.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(10,95%,59%),hsl(360,95%,59%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(360,95%,59%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(360,95%,43%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(360,95%,43%);
  
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(10,95%,59%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt deserunt velit in blanditiis, cupiditate possimus sapiente tenetur porro accusantium animi?</p>
  
  <button class="open">Modal</button>
</div>

<div class="modals">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore ab officiis libero reiciendis voluptas hic quas sit aspernatur exercitationem numquam obcaecati dolore sed voluptates, at aliquam cum harum, necessitatibus, expedita quod et magni? Possimus maiores vero suscipit ipsum veritatis, omnis pariatur magnam voluptatibus quisquam sequi veniam quas, et, dignissimos perspiciatis.</p>
      <button class="close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/giana/pen/gPGGgE

Но его можно привязать только к одному элементу.
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на несколько разных `div`, открывалось это модальное окно?
И еще, если не трудно - как сделать чтобы при нажатии на разные `div` открывались такие же модальные окна, но с разным контентом внутри?

Comment: Поместите код в вопрос, оформив как [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример того что нужно сделать: https://codepen.io/Telion/pen/jKyWwy

Для того что бы выбрать Все элементы с классом нужно использовать `querySelectorAll` вместо `querySelector`. Что бы к нему после этого применить обработчики событий нужно пройтись циклом:

```
Array.from(modalBtn).forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modalContainer.style.display = 'block';  
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        modalContainer.classList.add('active');
      },0.1);
    });
});
```

Для серии разных модальных окон вам нужно по сути сделать тоже самое, так есть пройтись массивом и назначить каждое к нужной кнопке. Тем не менее я бы посоветовал добавить аттрибут типа `modal-name="modal-menu"` и через него знать какой div открывает какое модальное окно. Будут вопросы создайте новый пост, буду рад помочь.

---

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Telion/41j8yro3/

```js
$('.open').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let modal = $(this).attr("modal");
  $("#"+modal).css({display: 'flex'}).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
});

$('.close').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.modal-content').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 600, function() {$(this).css({display: 'none'})});
})
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-content {
  background: hsl(250,30%,10%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s 0s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50em;  
}

/* Page Styling */

$font-size: 18/16*1em;

::selection {
  background: hsl(40,100%,65%);
  color: #fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: hsl(40,100%,65%);
  color: #fff;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: hsl(30,10%,90%);
  color: hsl(200,50%,20%);
  font: #{$font-size}/1.65 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 20em;
  padding: 3em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  
  &::before {
    content: '';
    border: 1px dotted hsl(165,80%,70%);
    position: absolute;
      top: 1.25em;
      right: 1.25em;
      bottom: 1.25em;
      left: 1.25em;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  p {
    margin: 0.5em 0 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(149,70%,90%);
    //text-align: center;
    //font-style: italic;
    //font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  }
}

.open,
.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(149,65%,74%),hsl(155,67%,68%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(155,67%,68%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(165,70%,55%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(165,70%,55%);
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%) contrast(120%);
  }
  
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(149,65%,74%);
    outline: none;
  }
  
  float: right;
}

.close {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(10,95%,59%),hsl(360,95%,59%));
  border: 1px solid hsl(360,95%,59%);
  border-bottom: 4px solid hsl(360,95%,43%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 hsl(360,95%,43%);
  
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(10,95%,59%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt deserunt velit in blanditiis, cupiditate possimus sapiente tenetur porro accusantium animi?</p>
  
  <button class="open" modal="modal1">Modal</button>
  <button class="open" modal="modal2">Moda2</button>
</div>


<div id="modal2" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore ab officiis libero reiciendis voluptas hic quas sit aspernatur exercitationem numquam obcaecati dolore sed voluptates, at aliquam cum harum, necessitatibus, expedita quod et magni? Possimus maiores vero suscipit ipsum veritatis, omnis pariatur magnam voluptatibus quisquam sequi veniam quas, et, dignissimos perspiciatis.</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="modal1" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore ab officiis libero reiciendis voluptas hic quas sit aspernatur exercitationem numquam obcaecati dolore sed voluptates, at aliquam cum harum, necessitatibus, expedita quod et magni? Possimus maiores vero suscipit ipsum veritatis, omnis pariatur magnam voluptatibus quisquam sequi veniam quas, et, dignissimos perspiciatis.</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.Я сделал по другому.Я в коде есть `var modalBtn = document.querySelector('.open');` Я просто сделал так    `var modalBtn2 = document.querySelector('.open-2');` а класс .open-2 я присвоил второму блоку. Потом там есть обработчик клика(который вы заменили) я его скопировал и просто поменял на новые классы которые я создал.Тоже открывает одно и то самое окно.Но ваш вариант круче и проще. Честно говоря я очень слабо знаю js и так и не понял что нужно сделать для разных модальных блоков.Если не трудно могли бы объяснить что к чему?Может на практике привели примеры(даже в том же код пене).

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Ну так тоже можно, но это неправильно с точки зрения автоматизации. Вы будете засорять код каждой кнопкой которую добавите и каждым очередным модальным окном. Вместо этого вы можете автоматизировать весь процесс одной функцией что бы после этого вам не приходилось возвращаться в код и добавлять новые обработчики, лишь добавлять новые кнопки и модальные окна.

Comment: Я вам благодарен,но я так и не понял как сделать что бы открывались разные модальные окна.Я что то пытаюсь делать но не выходит.Если вам не тяжело можете скинуть пример в каком-нибудь текстовом редакторе(в кодпен например).Если лень объяснять то просто киньте пример а я сам уж попробую понять что вы там сделали.Спасибо)

Comment: @ZELIBOBA Ну я сделал нечно но, конечно же, своими путями. В общем я добавляю пример в ответ, написан на jquery но скрипт будет обрабатывать любую кнопку/любое модальное окно. Попробуйте добавить остальные анимации сами, и, если нужно, переделать обратно в JS. В Js это забрало бы чуть больше времени, так что я пошел по-своему...

Comment: Ты интернет герой.Спасибо большое)

Comment: У меня проблемка с анимацией.У меня эти анимированные пузырьки переходит в новый блок и закрывает модальное окно.При этом только кнопка modal2 работает с анимацией пузырей Что делать .https://jsfiddle.net/ZELIBOBA/x8y3hbu1/   И после нажатия первой кнопки и ее закрытия вторая кнопка не нажимается